# Error using Chai and Jest to test `HTMLElement` DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jestjs, chai

Say I have a very simple component that takes in some `props` and renders a simple `<div>` for an invalid state:

```
// InvalidState.js
// Renders an "Invalid" state display

const render = (props = {}) => {

  // Create the <div> element

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('my-component');
  div.classList.add('my-component--invalid');

  div.innerHTML = props.message;

  return div;
};

export { render };
```

I'm using Jest as a test runner and `chai` as an expectations/assertions library.

To test the above I tried;

```
// InvalidState.test.js

import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as InvalidState from './InvalidState';

let wrapper;

describe('<InvalidState />', () => {

  it('renders the component', () => {
    // Call to `render()` returns an HTMLElement
    // (Specifcally, a HTMLDivElement)
    wrapper = InvalidState.render({ message: 'some message' });

    // Find an element by class name
    const invalid = wrapper.getElementsByClassName('.my-component--invalid')[0];

    // Test its contents
    expect(invalid).to.have.text('some message');
  });

});
```

However I get the error

```
expect(invalid).to.have.text(InvalidState.DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
^

Invalid Chai property: text. Did you mean "that"?
```

1. Are chai and jest the right libraries that I should use in testing HTML elements? Or is there a better alternative?
2. Why would the `text()` method above not execute correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your jest "testEnvironment" pointing to? `node`?

Comment: It's not set to anything, in which case I believe it defaults to `jestdom`? (See: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that `text()` only works with `chai-jquery`. Or at least that's what this cheatsheet says: https://devhints.io/chai

I revised it to use `innerText` and it worked fine

```
div.innerText = props.message;
```

```
expect(wrapper.innerText.eql(InvalidState.DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
```